# Replacing a string using sed in a lot of .cfg files in the same folder prefixed with MH

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I have a lot of files I need to replace the following strings in:

This:

```
,P6J\~aosl\}kBFB@pi\;FqBH\*A.@W.OD
```

with:

```
"(@)Vbd,si:Ou3iZ.(,I%m#O/a[bg<A"
```

These files all have MH. in their name.
This is what I have attempted but it seems to just drop me to > prompt:

```
sed -i "s/,P6J\\\~aosl\\\}kBFB@pi\\\;FqBH\\\*A.@W.OD/\"(@)Vbd,si:Ou3iZ.(,I%m#O\/a\[bg\<A\/g\<A\"\/g MH.*
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
sed 's/,P6J\\~aosl\\}kBFB@pi\\;FqBH\\\*A\.@W\.OD/"(@)Vbd,si:Ou3iZ.(,I%m#O\/a[bg<A"/g' file
```

Add the in-line edit `-i` parameter to save the changes made.

**Example:**

```
$ echo ',P6J\~aosl\}kBFB@pi\;FqBH\*A.@W.OD' | sed 's/,P6J\\~aosl\\}kBFB@pi\\;FqBH\\\*A\.@W\.OD/"(@)Vbd,si:Ou3iZ.(,I%m#O\/a[bg<A"/g'
"(@)Vbd,si:Ou3iZ.(,I%m#O/a[bg<A"
```

Comment: I am assuming the $ echo is for if I ran it in bash script? If I have limited the folder to just the files I want to edit with sed command by itself be sufficient? I am operating in CentOS5

Comment: Incremented for tenacious escaping. Still, stuff like this makes me wonder if there isn't a less error-prone way to search&replace metacharacter-laden fixed strings in the shell. This stuff is easy to get subtly wrong.

Comment: Yep, using the syntax he gave then less | grep the term until it matches correctly for my future sed commands of similar nature.